# Flutter Error - The method isn't defined for the type 'Future' - flutter sqflite database error

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am making an app in a flutter in which I can select the contacts from phone book and need to save them into the flutter local database sqflite. I have separate class for database named database_services.dart. In my other .dart file i m using

> var _data =  DatabaseService.instance.database;

then after that i m calling

> _data.getcontacts()  // Error statement

and

> data.insertContacts(model)

but it is giving me error below

*The method 'insertContacts' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. ry correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'insertContacts'.*

Both .dart files are attached for reference. What should i do ? what is wrong ?

my database class :
`

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'contact_model.dart';

class DatabaseService{



   DatabaseService._();
  static final DatabaseService instance = DatabaseService._();

   Database? _database;
   String dbName = 'contact.db';
   ContactModel model = ContactModel();


  


     Future<Database?> get database async {

      if(_database!= null){  return _database!;}
      else{
        _database = await initializeDB(dbName);
        return _database!;

      }

    }

   Future<Database> initializeDB(String filePath) async {
      final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
      final path = join(dbPath , filePath);

      return await openDatabase(path , version: 1 , onCreate:  _CreateDB ) ;

   }


   Future _CreateDB (Database db , int version) async {
//make like johannes mike at end
      await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE contacts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name TEXT,  number TEXT)',


      );

   }


    insertContacts(ContactModel modelObj) async {
     // Get a reference to the database.
     final db = await instance.database;


     //
     await db?.insert(
       dbName,
       modelObj.toMap(),
       conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
     );
   }




   Future<List<ContactModel>?> getcontacts() async {
     // Get a reference to the database.
     final db = await instance.database;


     var response = await db?.query("contacts");
    


     List<ContactModel>? list = response?.map((c) => ContactModel.fromMap(c)).toList();
     return list;

/*
     return List.generate(maps?.length as int , (i) {
       return ContactModel(
         id: maps![i]['id'] != null ? toString() : ' ',
         displayName: maps[i]['name'] != null ? toString() : ' ',
         phoneNumber: maps[i]['number'] != null ? toString() : ' ',
       );
     });

     */

   }


}
`
```

my other class:

```
import 'package:firebase_contacts_test/contact_model.dart';
import 'package:firebase_contacts_test/database_services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttercontactpicker/fluttercontactpicker.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'contact_model.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class Plugin1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Plugin1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Plugin1> createState() => _Plugin1State();
}

class _Plugin1State extends State<Plugin1> {

   var _data =  DatabaseService.instance.database;



  ContactModel model = ContactModel();
  List<ContactModel> _list = [];

  PhoneContact? _contact;

  String? _phoneContact;
  String? _name;
  String? _id;

  final Permission _permission = Permission.contacts;
  PermissionStatus _permissionStatus = PermissionStatus.denied;

  Future<PermissionStatus> _getContactPermission() async {
    _permissionStatus = await _permission.status;

    if (_permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      _permissionStatus = await _permission.request();
      return _permissionStatus;
    } else {
      return _permissionStatus;
    }
  }


   Future<void> printDB() async {

    print('printintgdsfssfdgsdfg  DB');

   if(_data != null) {
     print( await _data.getcontacts());
   }
   else{
     print('no contacts slected');
   }
   }
  pickContact() async {


    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getContactPermission();
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      final PhoneContact contact =
          await FlutterContactPicker.pickPhoneContact();

      print("my_contact");
      print(contact);

      _phoneContact = contact.phoneNumber?.number;
      _name = contact.fullName;
      _id = '1';
      //set into model
      model = ContactModel( id : _id , displayName: _name, phoneNumber: _phoneContact);

      _data.insertContacts(model);

      _list.add(model);


      setState(()  {

      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                printDB();
              },
              child: Text('show Db contacts'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                pickContact();
              },
              child: Text('select contacts'),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _list.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.contacts),
                    title: Text(

                        _list[position].displayName.toString()
                    ),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.delete));

                },
              ),
            )


            //     Text(_phoneContact ?? "contact not selected" ),
            //    Text(_name ?? "name not selected" ),]
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

my contact model class

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class ContactModel {
   String?  id = 'id';
   String? displayName = 'name';
   String? phoneNumber = 'number';


  ContactModel({ this.id, this.displayName,  this.phoneNumber});

  //setters
  set contactName(String? dispName) {
    displayName = dispName;
  }

  set contactNumber(String? num)
  {
    phoneNumber = num;
  }

  //getters
   String? get contactName{ return displayName;}
   String? get contactNumber{ return phoneNumber;}


  // Convert a Dog into a Map. The keys must correspond to the names of the
  // columns in the database.
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': displayName,
      'number': phoneNumber,
    };
  }


   factory ContactModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new ContactModel(
     id: json["id"],
     displayName: json["name"],
     phoneNumber: json["number"],
   );


  // Implement toString to make it easier to see information about
  // each dog when using the print statement.
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Dog{id: $id, name: $displayName, age: $phoneNumber}';
  }

}//class ends
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be the following:

```dart
await (await _data).getcontacts();

...

await (await _data).insertContacts(model);
```

This is because `_data` is an async property and needs an `await` to get the value out of `Future`. Also, `getcontacts`/`insertContacts` is async and needs another `await`.

Maybe it'd be nice to get the DB out of `_data` in another variable like:

```dart
final db = await _data;

...

await db.getcontacts();

...

await db.insertContacts(model);
```